# Comparing two columns in Microsoft Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

I'm attempting to compare two columns of data. One column (column G) is a "master" list with all account numbers in it and the other column (column A) only has a partial list of account numbers.

I'm looking for a formula that will compare the two columns and return a true if found in both columns or a false if only found in one.

Comment: If G is a master list, everything should always be found in it, correct? So a simple vlookup comparing column A cells to the column G content should suffice. If not, the likely culprit is as Bob mentions the content having spaces, or perhaps being string to numeric comparisons. a small sample might help determine that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably going to want some variant of VLOOKUP to get this done. The trick is that you want your VLOOKUP to return a true or false. My method for getting a true/false from VLOOKUP is this:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(lookup_value,lookup_range,index,FALSE)>0,FALSE)
```

this returns true if it finds a value, and false if it doesn't. (if someone knows a better way to do this, I'd love to know it!)

So now you put one of those statements for each of your columns inside an AND statement & you should have your test!

```
=AND(lookup test1,lookup_test2)
```

That was kinda long, but I hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks Roger!  I know this is a Excel 101 question, but I'm more than a bit rusty w/ formulas, so here goes:  I've populated my lookup value and range, but what do I designate for the index?  I'm also confused on the =AND statement and how I incorporate that in my formula.  Thanks again for the help!

Comment: Usually VLOOKUP is used where you want to find a value in one column and return a value in another column (like looking up a name & then returning a phone number), so the index tells tells excel which column the phone number is in. In this case you just want to return the same value you are looking up.... so put 1 in the index. http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/quick-reference-card-vlookup-refresher-HA101873816.aspx

Comment: Thanks Roger---still no luck in getting it to work.  Would it be possible to send it to you to see if I have it set up correctly?

Comment: Try breaking the formula out into 3 cells. One for each VLOOKUP function, and then another for the AND statement. that way you can test the parts of the formula. The vlookup statements should look like this =IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1,B:B,1,FALSE)>0,FALSE)

Comment: Also feel free to post your formula. Want to make sure future readers of this post get the benefit

Comment: Here is the formula I'm attempting to use: =IFERROR(VLOOKUP(G35,A3:A637,1,FALSE)>0,FALSE)  In this scenario the value of G35 is present in both columns, but it's returning a FALSE statement when in actuality it's true.

Comment: looks correct to me. The only thing I can think of is that you may have extra spaces in your data. Try finding out if the two values are actually equal, using formula =G35=cell_with_correct_value.

Comment: Still no dice.  I'll press on--thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

@Roger's answer is very close, but just a little bit off.

`IFERROR` does not natively return TRUE/FALSE.  It returns a specified value if the given formula results in an error, or the formula's result if there is no error.

Examples:

`=IFERROR(1/0,"Error")` returns "Error"
`=IFERROR(4/2,"Error")` returns 2.

The way I get TRUE/FALSE from a `VLOOKUP` is a combination of `IF`, `IFERROR`, and `VLOOKUP`:

`=IF(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(lookup_value,lookup_range,index,FALSE),1)=1,FALSE,TRUE)`

This says "If the `VLOOKUP` returns an error, return `FALSE` (i.e.: target not found), else return `TRUE` (i.e.: target found)."

Comment: I've recently also discovered `ISERROR`, which can shorten this up a bit.  Will edit later.