# Comparing 2 columns in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Comparing two columns in Microsoft Excel](https://superuser.com/questions/412149/comparing-two-columns-in-microsoft-excel)

I have 2 columns A & B both sorted from small to large. A has about 600 entries. B has around 300. Every number in B is included in A. What I would like to be able to do is in another column mark whether or not A is included in B.Should look like this when finished.Thanks.

```
    A  B  C
    1  3  N
    2  4  N
    3  7  Y
    4  8  Y
    5     N
    6     N
    7     Y
    8     Y
```

Comment: Combine `IF`, `IFERROR`, and `VLOOKUP`.  That's all I'm going to say, as I'm sure someone is about to link a duplicate somewhere here.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://superuser.com/q/412149/108226

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C1 write `=IF(COUNTIF(B:B,A1)>0,"Y","N")` and copy it over as needed. The intent is to count the occurrences of the item in `A1` in the column `B:B` and report 'Y' if that count is nonzero, 'N' otherwise.

Comment: As far as I can see that works great. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use the match formula. Documentation is given on the link below:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/match-HP005209168.aspx

Here is an example:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8618168/using-sql-in-function-in-excel