# Comparing two excel table (and matching two columns in each table)

Tags: microsoft-excel, comparison

I'm trying to do the following.

Table A includes two columns, if two items from the same line (one from each column in A) appears in one line in column two this line should be marked in Table A.

So if an item from Table 1 matches its place and SAP number in table 2 - this should be marked in Table 1..

I set up a quick example sheet - explaining Excel problems as a text is an exercise in futility:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to superuser. Please read [ask], then [edit] your question to clarify is it; `Table A` or is it `Table 1` and `Table 2`. Also, tell us what you've tried and what your question is. As it is written, you've only made a statement.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Comparing two columns in Microsoft Excel](http://superuser.com/questions/412149/comparing-two-columns-in-microsoft-excel)

Comment: @Matthias: I agree with CharlieRB: your question is unclear. The image helps a little, but is also hard to read. I don’t care whether your real data are ten digits long -- if I look at two ten-digit numbers (that aren’t one above the other) and try to decide whether they are identical, my eyes hurt. Please construct an artificial example using two-digit numbers, where neither digit matches. Also, Table B (which is labeled “Data B” in the image) has a “Place” column and a “Place B” column. That’s too confusing.

Comment: @CharlieRB: I agree that Matthias’s question is unclear. But you say, “…tell us … what your question is. …, you've only made a statement.” Really? He said, “I'm trying to do the following.” The “So how do I do it?” question is implied. And I disagree with your “duplicate” assessment.

Answer (score 0):

Not a quick, but the most flexible solution: Parse everything with a script like Python+xlrd, process the data in any way you like, and dump it out to another excel or csv file.